# how to use "from" field in outlook in "IF" statement - VBA - Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Item.SentOnBehalfOfName does not work. here is the example:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim prompt As String
prompt = "The BCC Field is empty! Send with BCC Field empty?"


If Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "someone@eomewhere.com" Then
    If Item.BCC = "" Then
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BCC Field") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

basically I want the messag ebox to appear only if the from field in outlook is selected with specific email address 
I found that the name for "From" field is .SentOnBehalfOfName but it does not work, behavior is like the if statement is never true

Answer (score 0):

Try the [MailItem.SenderEmailAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress) property, tt has to work.